# Like a post through the Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

Is it possible to like a post through Instagram's new Graph API?

It looks like the old [Instagram API has been depreciated, along with the liking endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/). Is this functionality just not supported anymore?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) for the node **media**, there's no way to like a post anymore.

The only interaction possible is [posting a comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/comments#create)

Comment: did you manage to find out if this was at all possible? From what I can tell it isn't with the new Facebook Graph API